# Connection row returns array implode error

Tags: php, mysql

How is it possible that this code:

```
$con->query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE user_username = :username");
$con->bind(":username", $username);
$con->execute();

if (is_array($con->getRow())) {
    $user_id = implode($con->getRow());
} else {
    $user_id = $con->getRow();
}
```

Gives me this error:
    `Warning: implode(): Argument must be an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\accreditatieModule\get_account.php on line 30`

I've tried var_dump($con->getRow()); which returns: `array(1) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "3" }`

I would like to know why this error is displaying even tough I first check with an if statement if the variable is an array. And I would like to know how to fix the error.

Comment: which is line 30?

Comment: Please see `implode()` function documentation first.

Comment: @Dormilich     $user_id = implode($con->getRow());

Comment: YOu need to add a string as the first argument of implode . for example implode(", ", $array)

Comment: if the username column in MySQL is unique it's a bit wierd to use implode..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think each call to `getRow()` is fetching the next row, so you need to store the result and just use that...

```
$row = $con->getRow();
if (is_array($row)) {
    $user_id = implode($row);
} else {
    $user_id = $row;
}
```

Although you are just fetching a single row, so you should be able to use

```
$row = $con->getRow();
$user_id = $row['user_id'];
```

Comment: I think a glue argument should be added for `implode` - comma or something like.

Comment: @u_mulder I think that too unless it has a default value. **Edit:** '*[Defaults to an empty string.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php#refsect1-function.implode-parameters)*'

Comment: @u_mulder, TBH - I think the last part is the proper solution, unless you have multiple users with the same username.

Comment: @NigelRen that is impossible in this case.

Comment: OK - so you should use the last part of the answer (`$row = $con->getRow();$user_id = $row['user_id'];`)